# Best way to get changes in a DataSet and save them to the database

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datarow

In a C# WinForms project that connects to a PostgreSQL database using Npgsql framework, I need to allow the user to make changes anywhere in the DGV and then, on a button click I need to initiate a process that finds those changes and commits them to the database.

I currently have the below code that iterates through the DGV's DataTable, in each DataRow it goes through each column and compares the DataRowVersion's original value with the proposed value:

```
private void CheckDgvForChangedCells(DataTable dt)
{
    string strOriginalValue;
    string strEnteredValue;
    int intRowIndex;
    int intColumnIndex;

    for (intRowIndex = 0; intRowIndex <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; intRowIndex++)
    {
        for (intColumnIndex = 0; intColumnIndex <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; intColumnIndex++)
        {
            DataRow drCurrRow = dt.Rows[intRowIndex];
            strOriginalValue = drCurrRow[intColumnIndex, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString();
            strEnteredValue = drCurrRow[intColumnIndex, DataRowVersion.Proposed].ToString();

            if (strOriginalValue != strEnteredValue)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The database table that populates the DataTable currently has just over 1400 rows, which will grow over time, along with 7 columns, and as I was putting this together I was wondering if this is the best/most efficient way to find all changed values and update the database as I find each one.

[UPDATE]

Per Steve's suggestion in the comments I tried working with the `DataTable.GetChanges()`, but I'm not seeing how to get just the columns in a given row that have changed.

I changed various cells in three different rows and `dtChanges.Rows.Count` was 3, as expected, but the entire row is in there, with the new values in the edited cells. I'm not seeing how to use `dtChanges` to update the database with just the changed rows' respective changed columns.

Comment: Why not [DataSet.GetChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.getchanges?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataSet_GetChanges)? or the same method for a DataTable?

Comment: However, if you have extracted the DataSet through a DataAdapter then you can simply call the DataAdapter.Update method (needs to have extracted also the primary key)

Comment: @Steve, I fiddled around with `DataTable.GetChanges` a bit, but I'm not seeing how I can determine which of the fields within a row has been changed. dtChanges.Rows.Count shows the number of rows that I changed, but each row in that has the entire row. Is it expected that I take that and build my update command on all values in the row, or is there a way to get only the cells that actually changed?

Comment: Consider that a call to a database is always a call even if you update a single field or the whole row. I don't think that you should get any noticeable difference in performances. But of course, if this is of paramount importance then you can measure the differences.

Comment: Also, every DataRow in a DataTable has a [RowState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.rowstate?view=netframework-4.8) property that you can check to discover if the row has been changed, deleted or added. With this info you can write the code to update the database.

Comment: Thinking about it, using `DataTable.GetChanges` at least allows me to work with just the rows that changed. I'll build an update on those rows, updating all columns - as you said, overall it won't make much of a difference, as I have to call the db anyway.

Comment: Yes, the big gain is working on only three rows instead of looping on 1.4K rows and comparing each column's row versions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that using the [GetChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.getchanges?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTable_GetChanges) method from the DataTable will solve your problem in a satisfactory way. This method returns a DataTable with only the changed rows and you can implement a simple logic to update your records. This will save you to examine all the 1400 rows and comparing each version value as you are doing now.

```
private void CheckDgvForChangedCells(DataTable dt)
{

    DataTable dtChanges = dt.GetChanges();
    foreach (DataRow row in dtChanges.Row)
    {
        switch(row.RowState)
        {
            case DataRowState.Modified:
                // TODO
                ExecuteUpdateCommand(row);
                break;
            case DataRowState.Added:
                // TODO
                ExecuteInsertCommand(row);
                break;
            case DataRowState.Deleted:
                // This is trickier. You cannot access any field in a deleted row
                // So you first need to call row.RejectChanges, get the primary key value
                // delete the row on the database, re-delete the row in the DataTable
                // TODO
                ExecuteDeleteCommand(row);
                break;
            }
        }
        // Do not forget to call AcceptChanges to set the table to a pristine initial editing state
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```